# Can I save images or load images from the client, instead of sending them every time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, client-server

I'm using node.js and socket.io, and I'm making a game. There are quite a few sprites I need to send to the client, so to lower the bandwidth I thought about storing the data on the clients computer. For now, the basic idea would be that it just downloads once, and then gets saved to the clients computer. But how do I gain control of the client's files? And how can I save pictures/general data on the client's computer?

Here is what I'm doing:

```
 self.sources =
  [
      [//trees, 0
           "res/images/enviornment/trees/tree_1_1.png",//0
           "res/images/enviornment/trees/tree_1_2.png",//1
           "res/images/enviornment/trees/tree_1_3.png",//2
           "res/images/enviornment/trees/tree_1_4.png",//3
      ], //there are many other pictures, but this is just the concept
 ];        

 self.images = new Array();
 for (i = 0; i < self.sources.length; i++)
 {
      self.images.push([]);
      for(t = 0; t < self.sources[i].length; t++)
      {
           self.images[i][t] = new Image();
           self.images[i][t].src = self.sources[i][t];      
      }
 }
```

Comment: "gain control of the client's files". run that around in your head for a while and think of why this is NEVER going to be possible.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably bad formulation... But there must be a way to save 20 pictures, with the clients permission, or load them at least, and have him download them from somewhere else. I mean, technically it is possible, whenever you upload an image that's basically it.

Comment: Yes... most browsers already cache static data for you automatically. Usually you shouldn't have to do anything for this to happen, unless you have a wonky server setup.

Comment: Which I probably do... I wrote the code myself from simple socket.io examples, but that's nothing that shouldn't be unfixable. But that's great news! So the browser does it automatically for me in most of the cases?

Comment: Generally, yes. Too many variables in play to give a universal answer, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers will cache the images, but the type of expiration is chosen by the server, and depending on the type, it may also be up to the server to properly handle requests for files where the client's cache is up to date.

If you want it to "just work," use Express.

To learn more about http caching, try this: http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-http-caching/

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9

Comment: That's simply too much information, I thought cache was a kind of processors' inner memory, a more "colorful" explanation would be preferred for this particular question... But that does seem like an useful source of information, so I'll read it along.

Comment: Hey, if your going to use the web, you need to know how it works.

Comment: there's many levels of cacheing. If you're thinking L1/L3 cache in a CPU, you're pondering things at a WAAAAAAAY too deep a level.

Comment: Yes, yes, I know, but I can't start head-on with things like that... As I said, I will read it along the way.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [html5 offline applications spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/offline.html). Beware, it's not supported everywhere yet.